# Sorting two JTables simultaneously

Tags: swing, sorting, jtable

I have two JTables built with different objects of same TableModel class. When I click on one column in Table 1 to sort, the requirement is that the other Table 2 should also get sorted based on the same column that was clicked on in JTable 1. Is there any way to find what column in Table 1 was used or the sorting was based on. Using that, is there any way to invoke sorting via any method call on  Table 2 for the same column.

Please provide your suggestions or pointers to any java apis. Also, if there is any link having an example would be of great help.
-Paul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to go is to listen to the changes of the table's sorter and set the sortKeys of the second table to the same:

```
    RowSorterListener l = new RowSorterListener() {

        @Override
        public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
            if (RowSorterEvent.Type.SORT_ORDER_CHANGED == e.getType()) {
                RowSorter sorter = e.getSource();
                otherTable.getRowSorter().setSortKeys(sorter.getSortKeys());
            }
        }

    };
    table.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(l);
```

If you need to keep the synch both ways, register the listener to both and add some logic to do nothing when the sort change was triggered by the listener.

**Edit**

after writing a nearly same comment twice (to the answers of suggesting doing the sorting on the model), decided to add it here

- technically, sorting can be decided to be the responsibility of either the model or the view realm. There are (strongly debated in the past) pros and cons either way. Once done, stick to that decision everywhere in ui dev
- keeping the index mapping between model and view coordinate system is where the challenges hides, either way
- Swing/X decided to regard it a *view* responsibility, cramming any model-based custom sort/synch on top is fighting the system

Answer (score 1):

I think the user interface only complicates the issue.  Think about it in terms of the underlying table data and you'll fare better.  If you can get that right, it's a simple matter of display.

Sorting a collection of values isn't difficult.  You can use `java.util.Collections` and `Comparable` to do that.

The trick is maintaining the association between the indexes of the sorted column and the rest of the columns in the row.

Comment: sure can be done, but that's not the Swing'ish way - sorting is considered a responsibility of the view (== table in this case). Implementing the "trick" is not trivial :-)

Comment: I don't agree - the Swing way might not always be the right answer if the logic is complex.  In this case, I think it ought to be somewhere else.  If the trick becomes too difficult, then it should be reconsidered.

Comment: then let's agree on disagreeing - it's probably on nuances anyway. My take is: if in Swing, do it the Swing'ish way as long as possible. If that turns out to be not appropriate, try something outside. You seem to recommend the other way round?

Comment: Yeah, my position is that if it hurts, don't do it.  If it's convoluted, perhaps you should think about doing it another way.

Comment: okay. In this case, it doesn't hurt - the OP simply doesn't know how-to, and s/he'll have to learn the ui way anyhow (or not do ui dev ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to sort the underlying data. Or you can implement a sortlistener and add it to both tables.

The following thread shows how to implement it in JXTable:

http://www.java.net/node/680987

Comment: "easiest" is relative :-)  Nice link digging, but a tad outdated - as of 1.6, SwingX uses core sorting/filtering mechanism